# How to set label width in v-slider?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

To align the Vuetify sliders to have the labels occupy the same width I need to resort to CSS. For example:

```
<v-slider v-model="s0" label="S" density="compact" />
<v-slider v-model="s1" label="Long label" density="compact" />
```

I need to put in the `<style>` section:

```
.v-slider__label {
  width: 3rem;
}
```

Is there a v-slider setting that does not rely on the Vuetify internals?
If not, could this be a feature request?

"vuetify": "^3.5.2"

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong with needing to use CSS to fine-tune a component's look, but for feature requests try the [Vuetify github page](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues)